# Shopware nginx configuration for subfolder installation

Tags: nginx, config, shopware, shopware6

I want to install shopware in a subfolder: `example.com/shopware`. To this aim, I followed the documentation I found on the [Nginx site](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/shopware/). Inside my Server block, I created the below location block:

```
##Shopware nginx configuration starts
    # Needed for Shopware install / update
    location /recovery/install {
    root /var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri /recovery/install/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /recovery/update/ {
    root /var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite . /recovery/update/index.php last;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|ico|png|svg|webp|html|woff|woff2|xml)$ {
root /var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public;
       expires 1y;
       add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

       access_log off;

       # The directive enables or disables messages in error_log about files not found on disk.
       log_not_found off;

       tcp_nodelay off;

       ## Set the OS file cache.
       open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
       open_file_cache_valid 45s;
       open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
       open_file_cache_errors off;
   }

   location ~* ^.+\.svg$ {
       add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'";
   }

    # Forward any not found file to index.php. Also allows to have beautiful urls like /homemade-products/
    location /public {
root /var/www/example.com/html/shopware;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Let php-fpm handle .php files
    location ~ \.php$ {
root /var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }
##Shopware nginx configuration ends
```

The configuration did not work and I got the below error message:
[image]

Any idea how can I make shopware work in a subfolder installation with Nginx?

P.S., I followed step 5 in [this guide](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-shopware-6) to install showare in the subfolder/directory.

Comment: You might want to leave only one `root` directive at the top level of the nginx config (rather than nested inside `location`, just like in the linked example. Is the shopware install located in `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware` or in `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public`?

Comment: Shopware is installed in shopware folder `example.com/shopware`. For example, when I visit `example.com/shopware/public`, I see the installation screen. Shopware requires the installation to be in a folder `(i.e., shopware in my case)` but it will read the folders inside the public folder `(i.e., example.com/shopware/public)`

Comment: You will also notice that the Document root directory points to the /public folder in the Shopware 6 installation directory. This is necessary because the frontend and the admin interface are located behind it, so it is not necessary to refer to the public directory in the URL in the browser to call the frontend or the admin interface. Please check the `Routing settings` on this link: [link] https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/installing-shopware-6

Comment: Please double check if you have a folder `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public/public` - that would mean you extracted shopware to the public folder itself. Can you list the contents of `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware/` and `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public` ?

Comment: @Alex, I do not have `/var/www/example.com/html/shopware/public/public`. The content of shopware folder can be found here: [link](https://ibb.co/WDqKv6n) and the content of the `public` folder can be found here:  [link](https://ibb.co/CBhbf77). You can ignore the `.nginx.conf` inside the public folder as I was testing the configuration.